# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I'm working on a project and I keep getting this error. I've done some research on stack overflow already and can't seem to find the solution. Here is my code:

```
$(selector).parent().siblings().find(".fullscreen-ad-type").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        player.currentTime(999);
});
```

Anyone know why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no assignments in this code. Most probably the error is inside `.currentTime`. Take a look at that.

Comment: Where is the error ? What does player.currentTime() do ?

Comment: The error happens as soon as I hit the function

Comment: Do you not get a stack trace showing the file/line number that is causing the error?